# Print out a List of animals

Tags: c++

I am working to get the list of 5 animals name from the user and list them. So, far this is what I have. How can I output 1. animal1,  2. animal2 and so on.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string animal;
    int num_animals = 0;
    cout << "Enter name of 5 animals of your choice. e.g., cat, << 
    dog, etc..   "<< endl;
    cout << ">>";
    cin >> animal;
    char temp; cin>> temp;

    while (getline(cin, animal)) {

        if (animal.empty() || cin.eof())
            break;
        else
            ++num_animals;
        cout << ">> ";
    }
    int a[5];
    int i;
    char j= ':';
    vector <string> animals;
    animals.push_back (animal);
    for ( i = 1; i < 6; )
        cout << i++ <<j << animals << '\n';

    cout << '\n' << "Bye.....";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many errors and problems in your code. I'm just not going to bother to list them.

It looks like, you're new to c++, or to programming. You should check this: [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Now, let's try to write program of your needs.

First, make a `std::vector` of `std::string`:

```
std::vector<std::string> animalsList;
```

Now, loop to `5`, and take input in each iteration, an animal name, and store it in the above created vector `animalsList`.

```
std::cout << "Enter name of 5 animals of your choice. e.g., cat, dog, etc..  "<< std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    std::cout << ">> ";
    std::string animalName; // string to store an animal name.
    std::getline(std::cin, animalName); // Input an animal name.
    animalsList.push_back(animalName); // push the animal name to the vector
}
```

The above `for` loop will run `5` times, and input `5` different animal names, and push them to the vector `animalsList`, and after the loop, you'll have `5` different names in the vector.

Now, write another `for` loop to loop through all the names and print them on console.

```
for (int i = 0; i < animalsList.size(); i++) // here animalsList.size() will be 5
{
    std::cout << i + 1 << ": " << animalsList[i] << std::endl;
}
```

That's it. Now let's see the overall program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main(){
    // declare a vector of string
    std::vector<std::string> animalsList;

    // Input 5 animal names and push them to the vector.
    std::cout << "Enter name of 5 animals of your choice. e.g., cat, dog, etc..  "<< std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        std::cout << ">> ";
        std::string animalName; // string to store an animal name.
        std::getline(std::cin, animalName); // Input an animal name.
        animalsList.push_back(animalName); // push the animal name to the vector
    }

    // output all the animal names.
    for (int i = 0; i < animalsList.size(); i++) // here animalsList.size() will be 5
    {
        std::cout << i + 1 << ": " << animalsList[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See the above program [live here](http://ideone.com/pn2jN8).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am a beginner in programming. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nice support for your peer. Thx.